# Help with $\int_0^x{\frac{1}{(1+t)^2(\log t)}}dt$

Tags: integration

Evaluate the integral $$\int_0^x{\frac{1}{(1+t)^2(\log t)}}dt$$

I tried integration by parts with $u=\frac{1}{\log t}$ and $dv=\frac{1}{(1+t)^2}dt$ but I just wasn't getting it.

Comment: firstly show is it converge?

Comment: Probably the x in the integral limit should be an y or something else?

Comment: I was being weird. I fixed it.

Comment: Issues at $t=1$.

Comment: It should converge for $0\le x\lt 1$

Comment: Are you sure that the problem is correct? Because this integral cannot be solved by elementary methods. In other words it defines a new function, an integral function, just like LogIntegral, SinIntegral etc

Answer (score 1):

There is a simple pole at $t=1$. Assuming $x\in(0,1)$, by setting $t=e^{-u}$ we get:

$$ I(x)=\int_{0}^{x}\frac{dt}{(1+t)^2\log t} = -\int_{-\log x}^{+\infty}\frac{du}{4u\cosh^2\left(\frac{u}{2}\right)}=-\int_{-\frac{\log x}{2}}^{+\infty}\frac{dw}{4w\cosh^2(w)} $$
hence by integration by parts 
$$ I(x) \approx \frac{\log\left(-\frac{\log x}{2}\right)}{4\cosh^2\left(\frac{\log x}{2}\right)} $$

Comment: Which is $\frac{x \log \left(-\frac{\log (x)}{2}\right)}{(x+1)^2}$

Comment: @Raffaele: yep, correct.

Comment: Should the 2nd and 3rd integrals you wrote have negative signs in front?

Comment: @user991003: of course, typo. Now fixing.

Answer (score 0):

If you make the substitution: $$ v = \dfrac{1}{1+t} $$ and rewrite the integral -
\begin{eqnarray}
- \int_{1}^{ {\small \dfrac{1}{1+x}} } \hspace{2mm} log\left (1-\dfrac{1}{v} \right) \hspace{2mm} dv  &=& \int_{1}^{ {\small \dfrac{1}{1+x}} } \hspace{2mm} [log(v) - log(v-1) ] \hspace{2mm} dv \\ &=& \left [ \dfrac{1}{v} - \dfrac{1}{v-1}  \right ]_{1}^{\dfrac{1}{1+x}} 
\end{eqnarray}

which does not converge at v = 1 (t = 0). It does not seem to converge for x=0 though.

Comment: It's wrong. The Integrand is $-\frac{1}{\log \left(\frac{1}{v}-1\right)}$
which cannot be integrate with elementary methods